# wifi bridge mode

Tags: wireless, bridge

I've a typical situation:

```
server1 - switch1 - link-bridge (AP1) <----> link-bridge (AP2)
```

AP1 and AP2 are 2 dlink-dap1360 (wireless N) with wpa2

so, if I connect my laptop to AP2 via cable I can "surf" about 8/10Mb/s (megabyte). Instead if I connect my laptop via wifi I "surf" up to 1Mb/s.

Using bridge mode I've half speed?

Comment: NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. Consumer devices like this don't provide the detailed information necessary to troubleshoot wireless problems. This is one of the reasons why questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many factors involved here.

1. The APs will adjust the data rate based on the received signal strength.  The weaker the signal, the lower the data rate.  Check the bridges and see what you're running at.
2. Interference.  If there is a lot of interference (other WiFi, for example), this will cause retransmissions and lower your throughput.
3. WiFi is half duplex.  Even under ideal conditions, you're throughput will be approximately half of the data rate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. What I don'understand is the differences between cable and wireless. AP2 via cable is fast, via wifi (connected to AP2) is very very slow.

Comment: If you're connected to to AP2, you're operating in repeater mode.  The AP has to receive your packet, then retransmit it.  That slows things down considerably.

Comment: So, a bridge link is the same of a repeater? Understood. Also connecting an AP via cable to AP2 speeds is very low...why?  What's the best way to have wifi without lost speed? (without cable). thanks

Comment: You could try using better APs with directional antennas so you can connect directly with AP1.  But that is a lot more expensive.  There is no easy/cheap solution to your problem.

Comment: Connecting an AP via cable to AP2 I've same problem... clients that connects to AP surfs very slowing...